# Solve recurrence 2T(n^1/2 )+c assuming T(1) and c are constants

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion

Got an 'Essential Algorithms' exam so doing a bit of revision. 
Came across this question and unsure whether my answer is right.

This imgur link has the question and my working.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvvts.jpg

[image]

Could someone verify whether i am right / where ive went wrong?

Comment: Please include all relevant code into your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Comment: @Pang, sweet mate thanks for the contribution x

Answer (score 0):

I can't really follow your handwriting to point out where you went wrong, but here's how I would do it:

```
T(n) = 2T(n^(1/2)) + c
     = 2(2T(n^(1/4)) + c)
     = ...
     = 2^kT(n^(1/2^k)) + 2^(k - 1)c
```

So we need to find the smallest `k` such that:

```
n^(1/2^k) = 1 (considering the integer part)
```

We can apply a logarithm to this expression:

```
1/(2^k) log n = 0 (remember we're considering integer parts)
=> 2^k >= log n | apply a logarithm again
=> k log 2 >= log log n
=> k = O(log log n) because log 2 is a constant
```

So we have:

```
2^O(log log n)T(1) + 2^O(log log n - 1)c
= O(2^log log n)
= O(log n)
```

I see you got `O(sqrt(n))`, which isn't wrong either, because `log n < sqrt n`, so if `log n` is an upper bound, so is `sqrt n`. It's just not a tight bound.

Comment: I think you need to set the cutoff on the RHS in your second snippet somewhere above 1, since the only way to get `n^(1/2^k) = 1` is to set k to infinity.  E.g. if you set it to 2, then the next recursion will have n=sqrt(2), which rounds down to 1, terminating things at last.  As it stands, the only thing that you can conclude from the 1st line of snippet #3 is that at least one of `1/(2^k)` or `log n` must be 0.  (And I don't understand the second line of snippet #3 -- what does "log n | log" mean?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I considered the integer part in the second snippet. If you're saying to round anyway, I don't understand why we need to set it to 2. If we're rounding (like I specified in the second snippet, added it to the third as well), then it can also be 1, no? `| log` means we apply a logarithm to that line, I clarified that too.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I'm still having trouble with the "taking logs of things that have been rounded down".  It might just be a gap in my knowledge, but I'm not sure what justifies your manipulations in lines 1 and 2 of snippet 3 -- RoundDown(log(x)) is not necessarily the same as log(RoundDown(x)).

Comment: I think `n^(1/2^k) = 1 (considering the integer part)` is equivalent to the statement `n^(1/2^k) < 2`, right?  From there I would conclude that `1/(2^k) log n < log 2`, and then that `2^k > (log n)/(log 2)`, and finally that `k log 2 > log log n - log 2`, to get the same conclusion (`k = O(log log n)`) as you do.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I assumed that the rounding down is inherent to the function definition. If you don't round down the square root in `T`, then there is infinite recursion because `T(1)` will never be reached. Your solution is nicer and it works even if you define `T(x) = constant if x < 2`, but I think in this case the rounding is implied in `T` by its definition, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I agree that rounding down must be inherent to the function definition, but that doesn't mean we can just round down whenever we feel like it as we do algebra on it ;)  I think your snippet #2 is equivalent to `RoundDown(n(^1/2^k)) = 1`, and taking logs would give you `log(RoundDown(n^(1/2^k))) = 0`, but then we need to "extract" the inner `n^(1/2^k)` from its enclosing `RoundDown()` before we can do further manipulations like transforming `log(A^B) = B log A` as you do in snippet #3 line 1.

Comment: As a potential algebra rule to apply, it might be that `RoundDown(log(A)) <= log(RoundDown(A))`; if this is actually true then we could conclude from `log(RoundDown(n^(1/2^k))) = 0` that `RoundDown(log(n^(1/2^k))) <= 0`, which would enable us to conclude that `RoundDown((1/2)^k * log n) <= 0`, then that `(1/2)^k * log n <= 1`, and from there the rest of snippet #3 follows.  This rule holds for large-enough A, but maybe not for all A...  But then maybe we don't need it to?  I dunno.